# How to create unique arrays of a given size from an array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

Given an array of Ints, and a desired array size, `myFunction` should return an array of all possible unique arrays. All the Ints in the initial array are supposed to be unique. An array is considered unique if all its members can't be found in another array.

```
func myFunction(array : [Int], arraySize : Int) -> [[Int]] {
    //... What to put here?
}
```

Comment: what's the purpose of the array parameter?

Comment: it specifies the element count of the arrays to be formed

Comment: then what is arraySize for?

Comment: the size of the arrays could vary

Comment: @Carpsen90: In other words, you want all k-element subsets of a given n-element set ?

Comment: Yes exactly @arcticmatt

Comment: ohh the array is the universe. ok thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then you want to create all k-element
subsets of a given set with n elements. This can be done recursively by

- combining the first element `a[1]` with all (k-1)-element subsets of the
  remaining elements `a[2] ... a[n]`, and
- adding all (k)-element subsets of `a[2] ... a[n]`.

Swift code (a bit *generic* so that it can be used not only with integers):

```
func allSubsetsOf<T>(elements: [T], withCardinality k : UInt,
    combinedWith prefix : [T] = [], startingWithIndex j : Int = 0) -> [[T]] {

        if k == 0 {
            return [prefix]
        }

        if j < elements.count  {
            let first = elements[j]
            return allSubsetsOf(elements, withCardinality: k-1, combinedWith: prefix + [first], startingWithIndex : j+1)
                + allSubsetsOf(elements, withCardinality: k, combinedWith: prefix, startingWithIndex: j+1)
        } else {
            return []
        }
}
```

Examples:

```
let result1 = allSubsetsOf([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], withCardinality: 3)
println(result1)
// [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5], [1, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 5], [2, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5]]

let result2 = allSubsetsOf(["a", "b", "c", "d"], withCardinality: 2)
println(result2)
// [[a, b], [a, c], [a, d], [b, c], [b, d], [c, d]]
```