# Swift generic Function (n choose k)

Tags: generics, swift, combinations

I'm trying to make this JavaScript code in Swift: [k_combinations](https://gist.github.com/axelpale/3118596)

And so far i have this in Swift:

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa

extension Array {
func slice(args: Int...) -> Array {
    var s = args[0]
    var e = self.count - 1
    if args.count > 1 { e = args[1] }

    if e < 0 {
        e += self.count
    }

    if s < 0 {
        s += self.count
    }

    let count = (s < e ? e-s : s-e)+1
    let inc = s < e ? 1 : -1
    var ret = Array()

    var idx = s
    for var i=0;i<count;i++  {
        ret.append(self[idx])
        idx += inc
    }
    return ret
  }
}

func kombinaatiot<T>(setti: Array<T>, k: Int) -> Array<Array<T>> {

var i: Int, j: Int

if (k > setti.count || k <= 0) {
    return []
}

if (k == setti.count) {
    return [setti]
}

if (k == 1) {
    var combs: Array<T> = []

    for var i = 0; i < setti.count; i++ {
        combs += [setti[i]]
    }
    return [combs]
}

var combs: Array<Array<T>> = [[]]

for var i = 0; i < setti.count - k + 1; i++ {
    var head = setti.slice(i,i + 1)
var tailcombs = kombinaatiot(setti.slice(i + 1), k - 1)
    for var j = 0; j < tailcombs.count; j++ {
combs += ([head + tailcombs[j]])

    }
}
    println(combs)
   return combs
}
```

But problem is that my function prints

```
[[], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 3, 4], [3, 4, 4]]
```

when it should print

```
[[1,2], [1,3], [2, 3]
```

What i'm doing wrong here? Im noobie at coding, and my javascript skills aren't very well, but that javascript worked for me, but in swift i can't make that work.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but this http://stackoverflow.com/a/25751214/1187415 might do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main error in your Swift translation is a misunderstanding about the JavaScript `slice(start, end)` method: That method returns the elements with an index from the given start index up to **but not including** the given end index. Your Swift method includes
the end index, which is wrong.

But Swift has already built-in slicing with the subscripting and range syntax. Example:

```
let a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
let b = Array(a[1 ..< 3]) // from index 1 up to (but not including) 3
println(b) // [1, 2]
```

Another error is (and that might be already present in the JavaScript code), that
for `k == 0` you have to return `[[]]`, i.e. an array containing the empty selection,
instead of `[]`. And this is in fact the only case that has to be handled specially.
All other cases are automatically treated correctly by the recursion.

And finally, in the general case, you have to start with an empty array:

```
var combs: Array<Array<T>> = [] // not [[]]
```

This gives the following method:

```
func kombinaatiot<T>(setti: [T], k: UInt) -> [[T]] {

    if k == 0 {
        return [[]]
    }

    var combs: [[T]] = []
    for (i, head) in enumerate(setti) {
        let tailcombs = kombinaatiot(Array(setti[i+1 ..< setti.count]), k - 1)
        for tc in tailcombs {
            combs += [[head] + tc]
        }
    }
    return combs
}
```

Some remarks:

- `[T]` is a shorthand notation for `Array<T>`.
- I have replaced the "C style" loops by `for .. in` loops which are more "swifty".
- The `k` parameter is declared as an unsigned integer.