# How to to generate all possible k-element arrays from n-element array in Swift

Tags: swift

I want to create *all* possible `k-element` arrays from `n-element` array. `k` may be bigger or smaller than `n`. The elements in the output array don't have to be unique.

For example:

given this array

```
let a = [1,2]
```

the function given a desired size `3`, should return :

```
[1,1,1]
[2,1,1]
[1,2,1]
[1,1,2]
[2,2,1]
[2,1,2]
[1,2,2]
[2,2,2]
```

example 2

given this array

```
let b = [[0,1], [2,3]]
```

the function given a desired size `3`, should return :

```
[[0,1], [0,1], [0,1]]
[[2,3], [0,1], [0,1]]
[[0,1], [2,3], [0,1]]
[[0,1], [0,1], [2,3]]
[[2,3], [2,3], [0,1]]
[[2,3], [0,1], [2,3]]
[[0,1], [2,3], [2,3]]
[[2,3], [2,3], [2,3]]
```

How to do that in Swift?

Comment: Could you explain where the difference to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749941/how-to-create-unique-arrays-of-a-given-size-from-an-array-in-swift is, perhaps with a concrete example of given input and expected output?

Comment: here `k` maybe be bigger than `n`, and the elements in the output array don't have to be unique

Comment: A concrete example would still be helpful ... You could also show what you tried to far and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want all k-tuples with elements from a given set. This can be done recursively
by taking all elements from the set as the first tuple element and combining that
with all (k-1) tuples:

```
func allTupelsFrom<T>(elements: [T], withLength k : UInt,
    combinedWith prefix : [T] = []) -> [[T]] {

        if k == 0 {
            return [prefix]
        }

        var result : [[T]] = []
        for e in elements {
            result += allTupelsFrom(elements, withLength: k-1, combinedWith: prefix + [e])
        }
        return result
}
```

Examples:

```
let result1 = allTupelsFrom([1, 2], withLength: 3)
println(result1)
// [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2], [2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2], [2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2]]

let result2 = allTupelsFrom(["a", "b", "c", "d"], withLength: 4)
println(result2)
// [[a, a, a, a], [a, a, a, b],  ... , [d, d, d, c], [d, d, d, d]]
```

Comment: How would the code change if `elements` were a an `[[Int]]`

Comment: @Carpsen90: I have written it as a *generic* function so that it works with different types. The first example shows that it works with `Int` as well. If you don't want a generic function then you can remove the `<T>` in `allTupelsFrom<T>` and replace all `T` by `Int` inside the function.

Comment: I like this generic form, I am just trying to apply this function to an `[[Int]]` instead of an `[Int]`, and I get an error on this line `result += allTupelsFrom(elements, withLength: k-1, combinedWith: prefix + [e])` after changing elements to `elements: [[T]]`

Comment: @Carpsen90: Sorry, I don't get it. What is the input array now? And what should the output be?

Comment: The input is [[Int]] not [Int] and the output is [[[Int]]] (all possible k-element arrays from the initial arrays)

Comment: @Carpsen90: Again: a concrete example would be helpful :)

Comment: @Carpsen90: Doesn't `allTupelsFrom([[0,1], [2,3]], withLength: 3)` just work? No need to change the function.

Comment: Yes! so sorry to bother you.. my bad